# How to initialize empty variables from your own type in Scala?

Tags: scala, syntax

My problem is understanding is the syntax of Scala. I come from a Java background. I am trying to make a variable of the same type as the class it is in. Example:

```
class Exp {
var exp1: Exp;
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Driver.scala:4: error: class Exp needs to be abstract, since variable exp1 is not defined
(Note that variables need to be initialized to be defined)
    class Exp {
```

Can someone explain why I cannot do this? I am new to the language. Any explanation would help in understanding it better.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because you need to initialize it.  Otherwise the compiler thinks you want only the variable's interface: the getter and setter methods.  It's very similar to how a method without a body is abstract.  The following will initialize it to null and give you a valid concrete class with a concrete variable.

```
class Exp {
  var exp1: Exp = _;
}
```

This use of _ means "default value" where the default is null for reference types and 0, false, or something similar for non-reference types.

Comment: I know the _ means wildcard in Scala, but what is it actually doing when you say that?

Comment: Added a bit more to the answer about that use of _

Comment: Your answer is correct, except the last word *non-reference types*. AFAIK every value in scala is a reference type, boolean, Int, etc. Please edit the answer or correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcard Initializer

in Scala 2:

```
var x: A = _
```

in Scala 3:

```
var x: A = scala.compiletime.uninitialized
```